# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Let $a_n = (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}$.

Now, $$n! \geq1 \implies (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \geq 1$$ and $$n! \leq n^n \implies (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}} \leq n^{\frac1n}$$

But $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac1n} = 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1$$ Thus by Sandwich Theorem $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}} =1$$ Is the solution correct?

Comment: Yes.  You have it.

Comment: Yes it’s correct by squeeze

Comment: $Limit_{n→∞}\frac{1}{n^2}=0$. So the limit is 1 what ever the powered number is.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n!)}{n^2} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log 1 + \log 2 + \cdots + \log(n)}{n^2} =
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n + 1)}{(n + 1)^2 - n^2} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n + 1)}{2n + 1} = 0.
$$
(Stolz-Cesàro used in the 3rd $=$)

Comment: I cannot see where did you get $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{log(n+1)}{(n+1)^2-n^2}$$ from.

Comment: @Tony, Stolz-Cesàro: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem.